# How to track downloading of file with Web Automation and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I need to download file from the page and to track how much time it took to completely download a file from web.
Does anyone knows how to implement it?
When i click " Download "on web  it opens for me a Native Mac Download menu, and i can automate click "Save File" by automating with a KeyKodes.

But the problem is:
How to check that, that exactly file or folder got completely downloaded? As well as track the time how long it took to download. Another concern if i will download folder for example with 300GB data, the folder will appear immediately but it will don`t mean that it get complete download of all files.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps, While downloading selenium jar file, it has ".crdownload" extension and after complete download it changed to ".jar" (This could be the approach to track whether file is downloaded or not).  not sure about time tracking.

Comment: That helps, but got another issue.
Not able to check file system with Selenium Grid environment.

But this answer is correct.